# What to say instead of "calm down" if you see the other person getting angry during the discussion?

Tags: communication, unprofessional-behavior, behavior

*Assumptions:*
Conversation is verbal. We will be talking face to face. In a heated argument, people can't be expected to stop talking automatically. They may continue to talk to prove their point.

In the middle of the conversation if I notice the other person is becoming angry ***but since the discussion has to be continued***, what should I say to "actually" calm the person down to avoid a fight at the moment?

From: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/93068/826

> Telling someone to "calm down" is, I think, rude and condescending in a professional setting. Especially if they are your senior. It might get someone to bite their tongue but is unlikely to diffuse tensions.

Comment: The obvious answer is still just "stop talking". Note that The Workplace does much better with questions based on a real situation rather than hypothetical ones.

Comment: "To actually calm them down" - any effective answer will describe a method of manipulation - not necessarily wrong, but be aware of the responsibility and of the backlash if you use it against someone to their disadvantage and they realize you did.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard answer to this question. What I do, won't work for other people because it depends a lot on the relationship between the people discussing and on the origin of the argument.

Comment: *any effective answer will describe a method of manipulation* Not so. You seem to collapse techniques with manipulation.

Comment: Hand them a copy of Hitch-Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy which has "Don't Panic" in large friendly letters on the cover. If nothing else it might confuse them a bit, which will distract them from their anger long enough to calm them down.

Comment: My go-to move is "Let's step back a moment, and look at this from a different angle."

Comment: the way to calm someone down is to stop aggravating them. That involves figuring out what is bothering them and whether you can stop it, and stopping and apologizing if appropriate.

There is no magic command you can use to control someone's feelings.

Comment: 3 options: 1. Avoid the conflict. 2. Postpone the conflict until emotions settle. 3. Negotiate as diplomatically as possible. It looks like you are looking for #3 which has libraries of books written about it.

Comment: If the other person gets angry, the discussion is over. An angry person is neither rational nor constructive so you won't get anywhere. You either need to wait until they calm down and say nothing or, if you can, interrupt the conversion and resume it later on.

Comment: Whatever the answer is, I sure could use it at home. Twenty years of marriage and I still have no idea how to say the right thing, apparently.

Comment: "Hold on a moment. I think there's a different way to approach this that may help"

Comment: Not a full answer, but for people interested in this topic it is normally referred to as 'de-escalation' and there is quite a bit of literature on it.

Comment: @dn3s: that's assuming that everyone is always rational, if the agitated person is causing distress or damage to others, the ethical move is not to let them be. Imagine a coworker losing it in front of clients or someone causing damage to equipment because of frustration.

Comment: "Take it easy, we're not making a Western"

Comment: Identify the reason why he is getting angry, make it clear through soft talking that that is not what you are saying. Example he gets angry because you are making it sound like he is an idiot, or he thinks you are trying to get improper advantage, state that that is not your intention and just keep the discussion going. This is sweet talking at its best. If he gets angry let him talk, hey i feel you are inconfortable and we really need to sort this out what are you thinking, dont worry you can be straight out with me. Simple alternative approach.

Comment: "This discussion is making me thirsty, mind if we make coffee while discussing" Or "mind if I make us coffee".

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you notice the other person getting agitated to the point of it being a problem to continue the discussion, just say:

> Hey, I think we should park this for now and continue later.

"The discussion **has** to be continued" is effectively never true. You can wait 5 minutes to cool down even in the most stressful office situations. Plenty of things can be continued the next day, which will give both involved time to cool down *and* time to think over the best way to continue the discussion.

If you're working in a field where you have to take literal life-or-death situations in a very short time, you (and your colleague) should have been trained to deal with just this situation, and you (both) should not be getting angry *and* know how to deal if the other person does get angry.

Comment: like "time for a pause for smoking? Even for non-smokers, we're back in five minutes!" ?

Comment: +1 - spending 5 minutes at unproductive discussion that only worsens things is always worse than 5 minutes break, no excuses (except life-saving but never have I ever seen such argument in life-saving situation).

Comment: Sometimes rescue workers that are emotionally impaired to proceed with operations are made to time-out, like "go back to the vehicle cabin". I know a firefighter sergeant, and he does that to his crew members.

Comment: @mindwin And in those life or death jobs (emergency service, pilots, doctors, military, etc) there's pretty much always someone with the authority to make a decision and end the conversation (even if they're the angry one, probably better to move on than argue)

Comment: Even in literal life-or-death situations, there's *always* more time available than you think. Can confirm both that we get trained on how to deal with them, and that there's a hierarchy that will come into play if necessary, though.

Comment: @Mołot If you've never seen such arguments, than you must have missed some Air Crash Investigation (Mayday) episodes. I can't find the right one now, but there are ones where basically the captain yelling at the co-pilot makes things really bad, and you can't leave it be for 5 minutes there... I mean, even professionals with lives of people in their hands are just and only people.

Comment: As a side note, I don’t recommend watching Air Crash Investigation / Mayday. I watched every single episode and now don’t really want to fly...

Comment: While probably well-intentioned, this answer brings a condescending tone to it: "I'm the greater person here, I'll walk away first", or rather "I'm deciding that it's time to stop this conversation for 5 minutes". It's a good tactic, which often works, but it can also be seen as highly confrontational and piss off the other person even more. Stian's answer, maybe even coupled with David's are far superior. But I suppose people like shortcuts, hence the popularity of this particular answer.

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed I agree that Stian's answer is very good, but this answers the question of "how do I avoid a fight at this moment", and it's (indeed) very easy to apply. People who really want to improve their communicative abilities need Stian's answer, but it'll take more practice.

Comment: @yo' Those accidents have resulted in pretty meaningful changes with crew resource management. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_resource_management

Comment: @BaileyS Yes, and they spend significant amount of time on CRM. Can/will you do that in an arbitrary company?

Comment: @yo' I am pretty sure it is an FAA mandate for airlines to do significant recurring CRM training. Some companies take it even further by setting policies further empowering the first officer if needed.

Comment: After you have let them finish without interrupting, calmly suggest "Lets take a step back" Allowing all involved to revert back to/before the point/point(s) that escalated the situation.

Answer (score 71):

1. Stop arguing. Let the other person keep talking until they're done. With luck, they'll calm down a bit by having their say. If they're getting more heated all by themselves, only then interrupt them.
2. Apologize if appropriate, otherwise do something close to apologizing. For example, "I'm sorry. I didn't mean to turn this into an argument."
3. Pause, if possible. Since you already let them say all they wanted to say, with luck, anything new they'd want to say would be positive, since you just apologized.
4. Find common ground. For example, "We're both trying to solve the same problem."
5. Again, pause. With luck, they'll respond in a positive way.
6. Acknowledge the legitimacy of whatever argument they're making. For example, "I agree with you that <variant of what he said you agree with>". So, for example, if he's arguing that a change you want to make shouldn't be made because it's too dangerous, agree that we need to carefully look at the risks before making the change.
7. If you find that you can't prevent the situation from escalating, make an exit. Just say you can't discuss it right now or otherwise extricate yourself and hope the conversation can be continued later.

Comment: If I am arguing "we shouldn't change that because it's too risky", and then someone tries #6 on me, then at best I will feel like I am being misunderstood, since actually I never said "we need to carefully look at the risks before making the change". 
That could just be me though.

Comment: @Wilson if you tell me that a change I believe is necessary is too dangerous then telling you that I agree that (... there are risks there, so...) we need to look at the risks before making the change is an  attempt at resolving the issues. If you cannot articulate what the risks *are* in a change, you won't persuade anyone of their legitimacy. Risk management around change should be about moving things forward by demonstrating that risks can or can't be managed and therefore the change can or can't happen, not about digging one's heels in and repeating "but my many unspoken risks".

Comment: @Wilson The idea is to make the strongest possible statement in support of their position that you actually agree with even though you don't agree with their entire position. If, for example, they're arguing against hiring someone because of the cost, you can acknowledge that it's important to justify every hiring expense and not to hire people that can't be justified. (Assuming you agree with them that much.)

Comment: You're missing 1b: **ACKNOWLEDGE.**  Apologizing or responding is *not* the same as simply *acknowledging* that you have received their communication, in such a way that they actually *know* that you have truly understood it.  This is a **[fundamental](http://www.scientology-losangeles.org/beginning-services/success-through-communication-course.html)** to communication and requires some practice.

Comment: #4 is my favorite - even during a heated debate, people tend to be rational & both parties want what is best - especially if your on the same team (i.e. same company), working together makes more sense than arguing

Answer (score 43):

[**Active listening**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_listening) always works. Always. It takes a few minutes, and it takes practice to do it right - but doing active listening right will disarm, calm down and bump people from a confrontational mindset into a constructive one with remarkable efficacy. It is impossible to become or stay mad at someone, almost to the point of it being ridiculous. I have actually tried to be angry and defensive at someone else while they were doing it, and it is **hard** to stay confrontational with someone when they are doing this. I hate to sound like a psych major, but it just puzzles me how effective it is.

So, what is active listening? In normal conversation, when two people are discussing a topic, the "ownership" of the conversation will flow easily between the two, when one has voiced an opinion, the other will chime in. It is a social event, and the one doing the talking will perhaps use body language, usually hands, head and eyes to underscore points. When this person is done with the conversation, we have small social cues for when we think it is OK to be "interrupted". We shift our balance, from one foot to the other, we glance at them, we breathe outwards significantly longer than "usual" respiration - there are many tiny cues that everyone picks up on. In a conflict, however, we do not lubricate our conversation with these things - we **confront**. We furrow our eyebrows, we set one foot in front of the other, leaning forward, or perhaps we instead lean back, crossing our arms in front of our chest (we are challenging, throwing the gauntlet). All energy and attention is being spent on refuting, challenging the other party and promoting oneself. Arguments cannot win, because this is an **assertive** domain, not a **persuading one**. (I imagine 4 domains, assertive, rational/persuading, attracting, empathic) Active listening is in the empathic domain - having a highly passive body language and concentrated listening - in order to interrupt the aggressive behaviour of your "opponent". The body language will make it very hard to (unconsciously) stay on the aggressive.

First thing first, you have to let go of your arguments, your viewpoints and your opinions. Put them somewhere safe, don't think about them. Thinking about the confrontation will change your body language and make you an opponent again. The idea is to remove the opponent to his aggression. You can bring them up later. Every second of the conversation has to be either one of two things. Either you listening to him or you reading back your understanding, digging deeper. (*"So you said [reading back what he said], can you perhaps explain more about [part of what he said]"* confirming that you have understood his opinion, and that you are interested in his story. You must be like a scholar, intently focused on trying to understand the speakers standpoint.

- You must NOT at any point, disagree - or argue.
- You must NOT at any point, take the conversation back and tell a story about you (believe it or not, this is probably the hardest point)
- You must NOT at any point start to dissect his arguments for the purpose of refuting them, just listen.
- You must use all the social cues for listening behaviour "mm-hm", nod your head, tilt your head slightly when he speaks, **keep eye contact**.
- You must *listen* - which is hard when you have to listen to both his words AND his body language.
- Keep at it until you see his aggressive stance weaken. Look for the "Angry face", where is center of gravity rests, position of his hands ("guard position" = bad), the elevation of his shoulders.

So, when you see the signs that the confrontation is dead, round off the active listening **gently** and still without confrontation:

*"I have a much clearer view of your standpoint now [first name], **thank you for taking the time to explain it to me**. You know, of course, I am concerned about some of the issues we have discussed - I'd appreciate it if you could let me explain my concerns - either now or at some other time."* - or something to that effect. You don't have to include the last part, you could say just thank you for explaining it and then round off there, and try again at a later point in time.

Comment: I think this is absolutely the best answer, and would directly address the OP's concern that *They may continue to talk to prove their point.* I do think the answer could be improved by some explanation of what "active listening" is and maybe some specific pointers for the OP.

Comment: @1006a Allright. I'll try to improve it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: That's a great edit. I already upvoted, but I'd +1 again if I could.

Comment: Needs more upvotes. The accepted answer, while probably good-intentioned, brings a condescending tone to it: "I'm the greater person here, I'll walk away first", or rather "I'm deciding that it's time to stop this conversation for 5 minutes". It's a good tactic, which often works, but it can also be seen as highly confrontational and piss off the other person even more.

Comment: I love this. Because unlike the accepted answer, which will not resolve anything (people entrenched enough in their opinions and ideas are unlikely to change that mindset after a 10 minute break, or even a week long break). If you're talking about something important and this person is in favor of something you believe to be the wrong choice, you need to resolve it. With this solution, you either learn that you were in fact wrong and they were right, or you trick them into invalidating their own views through explanation. A faulty argument always fails when faced with the right questions

Comment: (continued) And seeing that last paragraph, I love this answer even more, because thanking them for explaining their views and then bringing it up a day or so later is absolutely perfect - it demonstrates to them that you took a significant amount of time thinking about their point of view and noticed concerns, rather than seeing your concerns as snappy negative rebuttals. But I might leave out " I'd appreciate it if you could let me explain my concerns - either now or at some other time." because that sounds a bit patronizing. You're being a little too passive, nice at that point

Comment: Precisely, this answer is indeed, precisely today's best advice from psychologists / therapists / counsellors.

Comment: So how would you use this Active Listening if something has to be decided? Sometimes you can’t just lean back and be passive but have to step on some toes and convince the other person that their idea is bad (and your own probably better).

Comment: @Michael I wouldn't use active listening in order to produce a decision. It can be a vital part of getting team members "on board". Active listening is like a hammer. Everything is not a nail, but some things are.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Empathic communication style is just one tool in the toolbox. Sure, you can do without it, but in my experience - as a leader and as a leadership coach, active listening is absolutely vital. Everyone can boss people around, but getting people (in a non-military situation...) to follow implicitly requires a different mindset. Sometimes these people are smarter than you, those are the ones you want to keep. Can't bully them, they'll find somewhere else to be.

Comment: @Michael my comment yesterday elaborated on how one might use active listening to convince someone more effectively, especially someone stubborn.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I said the same thing except I think the technique is fine, he just over did it with the last line of his edit. That does indeed make it way too weak / submissive. While you're right that the person should probably told to control their emotions or take their unintelligent ass out of the company (in my opinion to be considered intelligent, one has to be able to discuss an issue objectively, open-mindedly, and calmly), but in many cases you aren't in a position to say that, so this approach could be used as a tool to convince.

Comment: @Viziionary: Certainly so. I think that there's a logical, reasonable and commonplace middle ground between this extreme suggestion and Stian's proposed alternative of "bullying". It really just comes down to "be nice" but I don't think we need a name for that.

Answer (score 20):

In many of these situations there is "blame" on both sides when things escalate into an argument.

Part of the reason people continue talking when they "should stop" (that's a bit loaded right there) is that the opposing party is not giving the impression that they are listening to what is being said.  Indeed, if you are sitting there waiting for them to shut up so you can talk, and/or trying to talk over them, you are likely *not* really listening, and the other person of course picks up on that.

Actually calming down *yourself* (it does take two to argue), actively listening, and then trying to find a common ground will naturally yeild a calmer, more productive conversation.

Comment: "Calming down yourself" is great advice to cool a situations. However, "In most of these situations there is 'blame' on both sides" is, while sometimes true (and you should always check whether this is the case), a fallacy which permits bullies to get their way with polite people. They make use of this fallacy to turn the table on their target. I would add this caveat to an otherwise constructive answer.

Comment: Yes this can happen, but we are not talking about bullying here.  The question is about avoiding arguments and cooling down heated discussions, with the intent of continuing the discussion.  There are too many caveats to cover for such a broad question, with no context to narrow it down.

Comment: The advice is good if we have an "honest" escalation, but I thought "In most of these situations..." to be a misleading statement. The counterpattern is that someone's  being baited only for the other side to be able to patronise them by seemingly soothing behaviour ("calm down"). That can well be a dominance display. Keep an eye out for that. This, to avoid being played this way, to play others this way or even to avoid just coming across as such unintentionally (which I understood OP's question implicitly to refer to).

Comment: edited to say "in many of these situations".  The fact remains that it *does* take two to argue, so checking your own beahvior is important.  In the event that someone is trying to power play you, listening to them will give you many clues about what they are up to and you can respond in a less reactionary way.  It is never bad to listen and stay calm.  There is no caveat there. You don't lose power by doing that.

Answer (score 12):

> people can't be expected to stop talking automatically.

Actually, they can. Everyone has a time limit how long they can monologue about the same problem if they receive no feedback at all. The time limit resets whenever they receive any positive or negative feedback on what they say. So it is important that you don't provide any.

While the person is ranting, look at the person with a straight face, but stay completely silent. Do not react at all. When they run out of words, mentally count to ten, and then start your rebuttal.

Deescalate the situation by speaking slow and calmly. Start by acknowledging their emotions ("I see you are angry about this..."). For most people*, showing anger is not about getting what they want, it's about expressing their emotions. Just showing that you acknowledge their anger is often very deescalating without forcing you to make any concessions about the actual subject of the debate. Then you can start to state your arguments.

Saying "calm down" actually does the opposite. It says "I do not acknowledge that your emotions are justified". It creates an additonal meta-conflict about you not taking their emotional state seriously. This further prevents you from coming to a solution about the actual subject-matter.

<sub>* there are also people who use anger as a scare-tactic to bully people into compliance. But this behavior can be dealt with in the exact same manner.</sub>

Comment: "I see you are angry about this" also has the potential of backfiring if you're misreading their current emotion (or how they've labeled it themselves). "I see you feel strongly about this" might be a bit more neutral.

Comment: I think this is outstanding advice, but I would be careful about labeling someone else's emotions, especially when it comes to anger.  It is possible that you might actually cause someone to feel anger over a statement like this, which can end up feeling like a trick: "I see you are angry"  "I AM NOT ANGRY" ("ahem, well now you are, aren't you?").  I think it's safer and more respectful to avoid labeling any emotions that are not your own, but if you must, I'd go with something more neutral like "I see you are very passionate about this".

Answer (score 10):

First of all YOU must remain calm.  Don't get angry or emotional, you can't think clearly and you will also escalate the situation.

Then you should try to find common ground. Ask questions that will surely yield a YES.

Comment: This. It's not so much what you **say** but what you **do** that will allow you to calm the other person. By refusing to add any energy to the interaction, it becomes a bit harder for the other person to maintain the elevated energy level they need to remain as emotional as they currently are.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to make sure they understand you're treating them like a person and taking them seriously, not ignoring their feelings or concerns.

> I can see this topic is important to you, and I may not fully understand your position.  Could you please help me understand better what I can do to help solve the problem?

Or something along those lines.  Basically, you make it clear to the other person that you understand that they're upset, that you take their feelings seriously, and you ask what you can do to help fix the issue.  Then employ active listening (as has been suggested elsewhere) and take what they say seriously.

Answer (score 4):

When you're in the middle of a tense situation, your mind has gone from "rational human being" to "holy tigers and bears I'm under attack!"

Rational thought don't enter into it.

The trick, then is to learn how to get from fight-or-flight response to rational thought. Somehow, somewhere, something has happened (probably something you did) to get the other person to feel like something is dangerous. You're going to have to find that reason, and telling the person to calm down won't get you there.

They're likely going to perceive that as an attack. Some options:

- It seems like you're upset/angry here, is that correct?
- I can see that I've made a mistake. Can you help me understand how I screwed up so I don't do that in the future?

Your only goal should be to make them feel like they are heard and understood. If you don't understand still, tell them! And if they try to explain a few times and you're still not sure, maybe take a break.

You should also try to explain as a way of showing you understand, but not parroting their words. For instance if someone said,

> You're such an idiot, I hate your stupid face!

And you say,

> So you're saying that I'm an idiot and you hate my stupid face?

That's just going to cause more problems. But if you said something like,

> It sounds like you have a problem with me, is that correct?

That *might* help. Of course it also helps to know your audience.

In any case, there are loads of resources out there that you can use, Crucial Conversations is a training that I went through that was super valuable in this area. If you get a chance to do some training I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

There are already some good answers. In particular I agree with the advice to arrange for a break, but I want to spend some time on *why* telling someone on the opposite side of an argument to "calm down" is usually disastrous. This can be useful for finding better wording, or at least avoiding poor wording. Even calling for a break can run into similar issues if you are not careful, e.g: "Let's all take five minutes to cool off." That phrase can easily come off as a passive-aggressive way of saying "calm down".

So, what's wrong with saying "calm down"?

First, it either is or is easily perceivable as being presumptuous. If the person is quite visibly angry, for example they are yelling and/or have aggressive body language (hitting things, aggressively leaning in), then your external assessment of their emotional state is quite possibly more accurate than their own self-assessment in that moment but only because they aren't in a rational frame of mind. If they don't agree with your assessment, then it will be perceived as presumptuous. If you only "get the impression" that they are angry, then you are literally presuming their emotional state. In the context that the comment you quoted was given, this was dramatically the case as it was an email exchange.

Following and compounding that, "calm down" is an *order*. It's grammatically an imperative statement, and semantically it's a command.  This is why it is "especially [rude and condescending] if they are your senior" and why Captain Emacs in a comment here states that it "[may] well be a dominance display". This is bad enough on its own, but (even as a subordinate) if I don't agree with the presumption that I'm angry, how can I comply with "calm down"? Heck, removing all the social dynamics aspects, "calm down" just isn't a very actionable command. It's like telling someone to "work harder". What does that mean? What do you actually want them to do? How will they know they are "working hard"? What if I don't know what to do to "work harder"/"calm down"? This is one of the benefits of "let's take a break"; it clearly specifies what to do and is a good strategy (even for yourself) for calming down.

Further compounding, why *should* they calm down? There are two cases: either they agree with you that they are angry, or they don't. In the former case, "calm down" comes off as "you being angry inconveniences/displeases me, so stop". This is a rather uncharitable reading, but there is little reason to expect things to be taken charitably in such a situation. In the latter case, they have to wonder what it is that they are doing that you see as indicating that they are angry. There's an apparent possibility. Apparently, the very act of disagreeing or arguing against you is perceived by you to be indicative of anger. Therefore, by saying "calm down" you are really saying "stop disagreeing with/arguing against me". Further, you may be trying to frame them as "the unreasonable one". Again, this is a somewhat uncharitable reading but is a likely consequence of the presumably oppositional situation and the vagueness of what constitutes "calming down". And frankly it may well not be in their interest to calm down. Applying this to calling for a break suggests against wording like: "Let's take a break so we can have a more productive discussion." "Productive discussion" comes off as code for "a discussion in which you agree with me".

Here are some potential tips on what to do, as opposed to what not to do. In a meeting setting, you may have some procedural rules you can apply, e.g. if discussion on a topic takes more than five minutes it automatically gets tabled. Even without such a rule, saying something like: "It doesn't seem like we're going to reach agreement on this soon, let's table this until after the other agenda items/let's schedule a separate meeting for this/let's talk about this one-on-one later" is an option. It is important to to have that follow-up aspect. For a more one-on-one situation, you can use your *own* emotional state to call for a break. For example something like: "Can you give me a few minutes to clear my head/collect my thoughts?" or even "I'm starting to get worked up, can I take five minutes to calm down so I can think about this rationally?" (I don't advocate the latter, unless it's an accurate statement of your internal state.)

Of course, to not just get back into a heated argument you need to first calm down yourself if necessary then reflect on what they were saying, what you might have said/done that prompted the reaction, whether your reading of the situation is accurate, what to say or do instead, if this "fight" is worth it, and even whether them "staying calm" is actually important to you or in their interest. For example, I'm reading Thomas Schelling's "The Strategy of Conflict" right now and he discusses how demonstrably curtailing your own rationality can be a rational strategy. Obviously figuring this out can be difficult which is why I find books like Schelling's, or Edgar Schein's "Helping" to be interesting and valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Think of how an animal would respond to "calm down". We, as much as we'd like to believe not, have a lot in common with animals. When agitated, unless a person has presence of mind to be listening,  nothing you say, such as "Calm Down" will be given some thought.

This is why it's best to just say nothing! Silence is golden. Just stand up and leave.

If the other person seriously cares about your opinion/ideas/bullshit, they will bring up the discussion *eventually..* If they don't and they just want to argue, they will probably try to get you agitated but at the point where you are calm and quiet, you probably won't be able to respond in the way they'd want, and would eventually give up.

And if you have no care about what people think about you and your ideas, then by all means, just AGREE with them, and just say:

```
"OK cool, I'll give it a thought. I'll catch you later when I have some questions."
```

Answer (score -1):

Something which works often for me:

I pose a question, which requires to go one step back, but is not directly related to the thing the person/people are angry or fighting about.

Answer (score -2):

I have sometimes just gotten up and walked away. It's probably the best way. My other recourse is just to start laughing, doesn't really help the situation every time, but makes me feel a bit better.

Comment: I guess the idea of the question is to find something which would help and not be perceived as rude. If someone walks away or starts laughing awkwardly I would perceive that as rude, maybe childish (teenagers tend to do this in arguments).

Comment: @skymningen if I lose my temper, I'm an ex bouncer, better if I walk away. I have had the odd person follow me out, didn't end well. But I came up through blue collar jobs.

Comment: While this might work for you, and judging by answers I've read from you in the past, it likely fits your personality. And to be fair if I worked with you It'd be a reaction I completely expected... I don't think it works as a general answer for the majority of people.

Comment: I think it depends of the situation. For example, if my boss or other coworker is **talking to me** and I'm angry or I can't interrumpt him/her, if I decide to walk away = that would be childish. In other hand, if I'm in a meeting and the meeting communication becomes heavy, I could say `excuse me a minute` and walk away for a moment (maybe 1-2 minutes would be enough) = that doesn't look childish for me `(or others - there are talking)`.

Comment: I think just getting up and walking away is incredibly rude and disrespectful.  Unless the other person is being more so (and I don't think the question supposes that the other person is being profane or shouting, just that they're getting upset), this is escalating behavior and not a good idea.

Comment: @Joe I'm a professional, I don't allow myself to get upset and I don't deal with others who do unless I have to. Whether they think I'm being rude or disrespectful matters little to me, I'm a busy man, if a conversation is going nowhere I leave. I don't argue until it becomes a shouting match, because I wouldn't be arguing at all unless it's my field of expertise and I know I am correct. Otherwise I wouldn't be arguing I'd be trying to learn more about the problem and be focused on finding a resolution.